# Why I am observing no speedp in a parallelised for loop in Julia

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia

#### THERE WAS AN ERROR IN MY CODE. SORRY EVERYBODY. THE REASON WAS THAT THE TIME NEEDED FOR LARGER VALUE OF X IS LARGER.

This is my code:

```
fit_s = rand(100)
fit_d = rand(300) 
LIM = 100
x = [2^i for i in range(-2,2,40)]
y = zeros(length(x))
Threads.@threads for i in 1:length(x)
    y[i] = analytic(x[i], fit_s, fit_d, LIM)
end
print(i)
```

*my_function* uses the two inputs to produce the output.
The problem is that it does not speed up the execution. With 1 threads it takes 27 s while with 8 threads 21 s(I'm considering only the time of the for loop).
What can I do ?
Thanks in advice.

#### Function

```
function alpha(i,n,m)
    ((n-i)/n)^m - ((n-i-1)/n)^m
end

function beta(i,n,m)
    (1-i/n)^(m)
end

function gamma(s, d, fit_s, fit_d, LIM)

    n_s = length(fit_s)    
    n_d = length(fit_d)

    app = sort(fit_d, rev=true)[1:LIM]
    F_DN = 0.

    for i in 1:LIM
        j = sum(fit_s .> app[i])
        F_DN += alpha(i-1,n_d,d)*beta(j,n_s,s)
    end
    
    F_DN
end

function mine_poisson(m,i)
    f = Poisson(m)
    pdf(f, i)
end

function analytic(m, fit_s, fit_d, LIM)
    Z = 1 - exp(-2*m)
    F_DN = 0.
    intm = trunc(Int, m + 0.5)
    if m < 20
        intervallo = 1:(intm + 20)
    else
        app = trunc(Int,m^0.5)*4
        intervallo = (intm - app) : (intm+app)
    end

    for j in intervallo
        for k in intervallo
            p = mine_poisson(m, k)*mine_poisson(m, j) / Z
            F_DN += gamma(j, k, fit_s, fit_d, LIM)*p
        end
    end
    

    F_DN += exp(-m)*(1-exp(-m))/Z
end
```

Comment: @MicheleAvella There seems to be a lot wrong with your code. For example, you are apparently computing on non-constant globals, instead of in a function scope, which will be very bad for performance, *especially* when multithreading. Also the fact that you are passing `data` into `my_function` in every thread, and apparently running `sort`, which either means you are sorting `data` in multiple threads, causing a race condition, or allocating arrays inside `my_function`, which is not good for threading performance.

Comment: @DNF I added the function so you can have a look. Thanks

Comment: There is quite a lot to be optimized in the calculation. Especially, everything which remains constant between iterations, should be calculated once. For example: `sort(fit_d,rev=true)` , constructing `Poisson(m)` and even `sum(fit_s .> app[i])` is constant-ish between iterations.

Comment: This happens sometimes ;p. You need to have a queuing mechanism in that case (eg. poll values of `i` from some queue). Just remember to use locks in that case!

Comment: Based on the updated code, the first thing to do is to sort `fit_d`, and maybe also `fit_s` outside the threaded loop, and exploit their sortedness inside `gamma`. It should be possible to avoid all allocations, afaict, which should be beneficial for threaded performance.

Answer (score 2):

You code looks correct.

There are the following reasons why you might not observe the speedup:

- you forgot the `-t` parameter when starting Julia. Use `Threads.nthreads()` to check the actual number of threads loaded
- your operating system is heavily loaded with other tasks
- [most likely] your function `my_function` is using parallelized code via BLAS. In order to find out the BLAS configuration try:

  ```
  using LinearAlgebra  
  LinearAlgebra.BLAS.get_num_threads()
  ```

  BLAS is used for linear algebra operations such as matrix multiplications. In that case the call  `my_function` would be using most of threads already and hence small speedup is observed
- some other libraries such as `DataFrames` are [utilizing threading support for selected operations](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/)
- other issues such as false sharing or race condition (does not look to be the case in your code)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Inside `my_function` I'm using 3 built in functions:

`sort`,

`findmax`

,`Poisson`.

Do they use BLAS ? If yes how can I set it to 1?

Comment: You could set `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` system variable or use `LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads()`. `Poisson` is from library `Distributions` which for sure does linear algebra operations.

Comment: @MecheleAvella Are you `sort`ing the `data` vector simultaneously in several different threads? That would mean that the different threads step on each other's toes. Also, always wrap your code in a function.

Comment: `sort`, `findmax` and `Poisson` do not use BLAS. Is your code too long to share?

Comment: That partially worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel When briefly looking I could not find any traces of BLAS in relation to `Poisson`. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @DNF I am not sure.  All I did I have just looked at https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/blob/master/Project.toml and see that `LinearAlgebra` is among dependencies. I did not though do any exact code dive.  On the other hand we do not know what the code of Michele is exactly doing :)